# How to setAttribute a href in a li tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm coding an intranet.

I wrote my code in HTML. Now I'm rewriting the HTML code in JS, so that I can add, modify and delete dynamically some content.

I have to use `mySection.setAttribute("class", "myClass");` to give class, id,... to my tags. 
When there is only a class or an id there is no problem. But now I have to rewrite in JS this line :

```js
<li><a href="https://www.google.ch/" target="_blank">Yahoo</a></li>
```

I can't solve my problem I have been trying and searching on the internet...but nothing seems to be like my problem.

Comment: Writing all HTML in JS is probably very cumbersome and error-prone. Have you looked into templating libraries like [nunjucks](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/) or [handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/)?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This might be helpful to achieve your goal.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var a =document.querySelector("a[href$='.ch']");
  a.setAttribute("class", "democlass");
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hmm, I do not see the question tagged jQuery nor is the example code jQuery

Answer (score 2):

You mean

```js
// Create new links

var ul = document.getElementById("linkList"),
    li = document.createElement("li"), 
     a = document.createElement("a"); 
a.href="https://www.google.ch/";  // or a.setAttribute("href","https://www.google.ch/");
a.target="_blank"; 
a.innerText="Yahoo"; 
li.appendChild(a); 
ul.appendChild(li);

// If you need to change the link and it does not have any class, you can do something like
document.querySelectorAll("#linkList li > a[target=_blank]").forEach(lnk => {
  lnk.className = "red";
  // more classes? 
  lnk.classList.add("no_underline");
});
```

```css
.red { color:red }
.no_underline { text-decoration:none }
```

```html
<ul id="linkList">
<li><a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/" target="_blank">MDN</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, that's that !

Comment: @Lucas1564 - not sure what you want if you accepted the other answer, which is jQuery. I updated my answer